# Update the existing xml attributes values (same multiple key-value pairs under one tag)using BeautifulSoup Python?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

List elements to be appended in XML data:

```
Sorted_TestSpecID: [10860972, 10860972, 10860972, 10860972, 10860972]
Sorted_TestCaseID: [16961435, 16961462, 16961739, 16961741, 16961745]
Sorted_TestText  : ['SIG1', 'SIG2', 'SIG3', 'SIG4', 'SIG5']
```

original xml data:

```xml
<tc>
  <title>SIG1</title>
  <tcid>2c758925-dc3d-4b1d-a5e2-e0ca54c52a47</tcid>
  <attributes>
    <attr>
      <key>TestSpec ID</key>
      <value>1</value>
    </attr>
    <attr>
      <key>TestCase ID</key>
      <value>2</value>
    </attr>
  </attributes>
</tc>
```

Trying Python script to:

1. Search title SIG1 in xml data from Sorted_TestText
2. Then it should search for Key =TestCase ID and update the corresponding 16961435 value
3. Then it shall check for its resp.
   Key =TestSpec ID and update the corresponding 10860972.

I am able to append TestCase ID with below code but all value attributes are getting updated with Sorted_TestCaseID list.
Intention is that Values shall get updated in XML based on key attributes(Sorted_TestSpecID & Sorted_TestCaseID). Stuck here in differentiating two value attributes based on key.

Any sort of help shall be appreciated.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'xml') 
all_items = soup.find_all('tc')  
for set in all_items:                                                           
    title = set.find('title').text                                         
    print (title)                                              
    if title in Sorted_TestText:                                                 
        for p, new_value in zip(soup.select('value'), Sorted_TestCaseID):    
        p.string = str(new_value)
```

Comment: Avoid naming objects similar to built-in methods like `set`.

Comment: Getting attr.find('value').text = spec
AttributeError: can't set attribute ; Looks text attribute is read-only so we can't modify it.

Comment: Worked with "attr.find('value').string = str(spec) ". Thanks a ton @Parfait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding an `attributes` level loop after zipping through list elements. Then, conditionally check keys for value assignment:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'xml') 

for tc in soup.find_all('tc'):
    for title, spec, case in zip(Sorted_TestText, Sorted_TestSpecID, Sorted_TestCaseID):    
        if tc.find('title').text == title:
            for attr in tc.find_all('attr'):
                if attr.find('key').text == "TestSpec ID":
                    attr.find('value').text = str(spec)
                if attr.find('key').text == "TestCase ID"
                    attr.find('value').text = str(case)

print(soup)
```

Comment: This script is not updating spec and case based on title, working on if spec, case and title are in order. My intention was script shall look for title and then it shall update its respective attributes. Lets say in my xml 'SIG1', 'SIG2', 'SIG3' are not present; I want to update spec and case of SIG4 with spec: 10860972 case: 16961741, but with this script it is updating SIG4 as spec: 10860972 case: 16961435. Need to traverse the spec and case lists as well for respective title. I tried, but no luck.; Required support here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regardless of what your XML contains, make sure the three lists at top of your post always exists and are at equal length, so `zip` will iterate elementwise. If lists differ in length, `zip` only runs to the shortest length. Please post the exact XML that renders what you describe with this solution.

Comment: Text column is not same size as case and spec because I filtered out required list string elements from text list. What would different approach we shall adapt?